# Cannot close plot generated with matplotlib in ipython notebook

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to make a plot using matplotlib in ipython notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

I get the desired plot, but when I try to close it, it hangs. I then have to force quit it, and restart the kernel.

If I run the same code from terminal, I can safely close the plot. The error is when using ipython notebook.

I am on OS X El Capitan (10.11.2), python 2.7. The issue began after updating to El Capitan.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your work in a notebook, it is better to display the plots inline. Turn on the inline mode:

```
In: [1] %matplotlib inline
```

Now, plot without the `plt.show()`:

```
In: [2]import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In: [3]plt.plot(range(10))
```

The plot should appear right in the notebook.

For interactive plots in the notebook use [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io). Just add these lines to your notebook:

```
import mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
```

Comment: But then I lose the interactivity, I might need to zoom and so on.

Comment: @user104493 Not necessarily. See the addition to my answer.